# How can I convert a color name to a 3 element RGB vector?

Tags: matlab, colors, rgb

In many MATLAB plotting functions, you can specify the color as either a string or as a 3 element vector that directly lists the red, green, and blue values.

For instance, these two statements are equivalent:

```
plot(x, y, 'Color', 'r');
plot(x, y, 'Color', [1 0 0]);
```

There are 8 colors that can be specified by a string value: `'r','g','b','c','m','y','k','w'`. Is there a MATLAB built-in function that converts these strings to an equivalent RGB vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R2020b you can use [`validatecolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validatecolor.html) for this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34888684)

Comment: @dcolazin This does answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

I found this general alternative on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) which will even handle color strings other than the default 8 in MATLAB:

- [rgb.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1805-rgb-m) by [Ben Mitch](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/2765)

If you're only concerned with conversions for the default 8 color strings, here's a function I wrote myself that I use to convert back and forth between RGB triples and short color names (i.e. single characters):

```
function outColor = convert_color(inColor)

  charValues = 'rgbcmywk'.';  %#'
  rgbValues = [eye(3); 1-eye(3); 1 1 1; 0 0 0];
  assert(~isempty(inColor),'convert_color:badInputSize',...
         'Input argument must not be empty.');

  if ischar(inColor)  %# Input is a character string

    [isColor,colorIndex] = ismember(inColor(:),charValues);
    assert(all(isColor),'convert_color:badInputContents',...
           'String input can only contain the characters ''rgbcmywk''.');
    outColor = rgbValues(colorIndex,:);

  elseif isnumeric(inColor) || islogical(inColor)  %# Input is a numeric or
                                                   %#   logical array
    assert(size(inColor,2) == 3,'convert_color:badInputSize',...
           'Numeric input must be an N-by-3 matrix');
    inColor = double(inColor);           %# Convert input to type double
    scaleIndex = max(inColor,[],2) > 1;  %# Find rows with values > 1
    inColor(scaleIndex,:) = inColor(scaleIndex,:)./255;  %# Scale by 255
    [isColor,colorIndex] = ismember(inColor,rgbValues,'rows');
    assert(all(isColor),'convert_color:badInputContents',...
           'RGB input must define one of the colors ''rgbcmywk''.');
    outColor = charValues(colorIndex(:));

  else  %# Input is an invalid type

    error('convert_color:badInputType',...
          'Input must be a character or numeric array.');

  end
```

Note that this function allows you to input either a string of characters *or* an N-by-3 numeric or logical array (with RGB values from 0 to 1 or 0 to 255) and it returns the opposite color representation. It also uses the function [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) to do the conversions.

Comment: actually, if you open up ismember.m, it uses for-loops internally for small sets and then sorts for large sets, so it's not obvious that it's faster; but this is nice & likely easier to generalize;  also good tip on the rgb.m

Comment: @Marc: True, if performance is critical you would probably want to write your own loops to avoid any extra overhead from input-checking and formatting that may come with using ISMEMBER, but when speed isn't an issue ISMEMBER makes the code shorter and easy to read.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a function for this in matlab. I suggest you use Marcs function, or this one-liner.

```
C = rem(floor((strfind('kbgcrmyw', C) - 1) * [0.25 0.5 1]), 2);
```

Comment: Here's an even shorter one: `C = bitget(find('krgybmcw'==C)-1,1:3);`

Answer (score 5):

In case there isn't, I just hacked one together

```
function rgbvec = char2rgb (charcolor)
%function rgbvec = char2rgb (charcolor)
%
%converts a character color (one of 'r','g','b','c','m','y','k','w') to a 3
%value RGB vector
%if charcolor is a string (vector of chars), the result is a Nx3 matrix of
%color values, where N is the length of charcolor

if (~exist(charcolor,'var') || ~ischar(charcolor))
    warning('RGB2VEC:NOTC', 'You must pass a character (rgbcmykw)');
    rgbvec = [0 0 0];
    return;
end
rgbvec = zeros(length(charcolor), 3);
charwarning = false;
for j = 1:length(charcolor)
    switch(lower(charcolor(j)))
        case 'r'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [1 0 0];
        case 'g'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [0 1 0];
        case 'b'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [0 0 1];
        case 'c'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [0 1 1];
        case 'm'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [1 0 1];
        case 'y'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [1 1 0];
        case 'w'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [1 1 1];
        case 'k'
            rgbvec(j,:) = [0 0 0];
        otherwise
            charwarning = true;
    end
end

if (charwarning)
    warning('RGB2VEC:BADC', 'Only r,g,b,c,m,y,k,and w are recognized colors');
end
```

Comment: I got the cmyk values from get(plot(x,y,'Color','c'), 'Color')) which etc.

Comment: You can actually avoid using for loops and switch statements by using functions like [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922383/matlab-convert-color-name-to-rgb-3-element-vector/4923343#4923343) for an example). Also, your warnings would make more sense as [errors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/error.html).

Comment: Instead of the `exist` statement, I generally prefer to use `if nargin < 1` to check for the existence of the first input, since `exist` tends to be slow (also, there's less typing). Also, I think you may want to throw an error instead of a warning.

Comment: nice and useful function, one small note - 
it would be in line 9:  
      if (~exist('charcolor','var') || ~ischar(charcolor)) 
and not
     if (~exist(charcolor,'var') || ~ischar(charcolor))

Answer (score 3):

here's a oneliner you don't have to solve for C:

```
str2rgb=@(x)get(line('color',x),'color');
```

Now `str2rgb` gives you the answer. for example `str2rgb('c') = [0 1 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no MATLAB built-in function** to convert `'r','g','b','c','m','y','k','w'` to the respective RGB colours because all these cases are well known to be **BASIC colours**.

Every one blending **BASIC colours** should know each and all of them, at all times.

In any case it may be useful to build a table or define constants using the following values:

**1.- Primary additive colours**

red green blue

```
r [255 0 0]
g [0 255 0]
b [0 0 255]
```

**2.- Primary subtractive colours**

cyan magenta yellow

```
c [0 255 255]
m [255 0 255]
y [255 255 0]
```

**3.- black : absence of any colour**

```
k [0 0 0]
```

**4.- white : all colours**

```
w [255 255 255]
```

Note that in MATLAB the command `plot` requires field `'Color'` input with range `[0 1]`.

so whatever values `[0 255]` used divide them by `255` to plot custom colours.