# How to convert MATLAB fixed color to RGB value?

Tags: matlab, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB: convert color name to RGB 3 element vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922383/matlab-convert-color-name-to-rgb-3-element-vector)

MATLAB's [ColorSpec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html) concept allows a color to be defined either as a RGB 3-tuple or a fixed color string. I could build a function that uses a lookup table based on the data at the above link to convert between these two color definitions but I worry about changes to this table in future releases.

Is there a built-in function which converts from fixed color to RGB value that does something like the following?

```
>> fixedColor2RGB('r')

ans = 

     [1 0 0]
```

Comment: Hmmm, thought this sounded familiar: [MATLAB: convert color name to RGB 3 element vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922383/matlab-convert-color-name-to-rgb-3-element-vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function to convert between short or long color name strings and their corresponding RGB triplets. However, [these fixed color strings have been the standard](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html) in MATLAB for as long as I've used it (about 15 years):

[image]

So I wouldn't worry too much about changes to this in the future. A simple table lookup should do just fine. And even if they *did* change things (which seems unlikely), such a simple utility could be easily updated.